# Libcurl display log messages even the CURLOPT_VERBOSE is not activated

Tags: c++, c, curl, libcurl

I'm using libcurl to send http message.

I developed the following function in which I initiate curl options and then perform a send of a http message. the option `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` is not activated in the following code. But when executing the following function, the received http message is displayed in the verbose. How I can fix that ?

```
http_lightweight_notification(char *msg_out, int msg_out_len)
{
    static CURL *n_curl;
    CURLcode res;
    struct curl_slist *chunk = NULL;
    char *url="http://192.168.1.133:8080";
    char buf[SIGNATURE_LEN + sizeof("Signature: ")] = "Signature: ";
    char *signature = buf + sizeof("Signature: ") - 1;

    if (!msg_out) return -1;
    n_curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (!n_curl) return -1;

    signature_hmac_sha1(msg_out, "anykey", signature);

    chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    if (!chunk) return -1;
    chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Accept:");
    if (!chunk) return -1;
    chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, buf);
    if (!chunk) return -1;

    curl_easy_setopt(n_curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(n_curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, chunk);
    curl_easy_setopt(n_curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_easy_setopt(n_curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);

    curl_easy_setopt(n_curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, msg_out);
    curl_easy_setopt(n_curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long) msg_out_len);

# if 0
    curl_easy_setopt(n_curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
# endif

    res = curl_easy_perform(n_curl);
    if (chunk) {
        curl_slist_free_all(chunk);
        chunk = NULL;
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(n_curl);
    curl_global_cleanup();

    if (res) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

The verbose output is:

```
<html><head><title>JBossWeb/2.0.1.GA - Rapport d'erreur</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>Etat HTTP 500 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Rapport d'exception</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>Le serveur a rencontrأ� une erreur interne () qui l'a empأ�chأ� de satisfaire la requأ�te.</u></p><p><b>exception</b> <pre>org.jboss.ws.core.CommonSOAPFaultException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
        org.jboss.ws.core.soap.EnvelopeBuilderDOM.build(EnvelopeBuilderDOM.java:93)
        org.jboss.ws.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:262)
        org.jboss.ws.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:185)
        org.openacs.ACSServlet.processRequest(ACSServlet.java:331)
        org.openacs.ACSServlet.doPost(ACSServlet.java:588)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
</pre></p><p><b>note</b> <u>La trace complأ�te de la cause mأ�re de cette erreur est disponible dans les fichiers journaux de JBossWeb/2.0.1.GA.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>JBossWeb/2.0.1.GA</h3></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the verbose output, that's the body of the content you receive.

You inhibit the content to get sent to stdout (which is the default) by setting the [CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) to receive the data, or possibly set [CURLOPT_WRITEDATA](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.html) to a different FILE * handle.

Shown in the [getinmemory.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html) example among others.